# How to get XAML Design Previewer in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
**This is XAML Source Code:**

<Grid Grid.Row="0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="Select.." HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="set_text">

    </Label>
    <Image Source="drop_down.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" IsVisible="true" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="image_dropdown">
      <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTap_Select"/>
      </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
  </StackLayout>


  <ListView x:Name="list_spinner" HasUnevenRows="True" IsVisible="false"  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="10,20,10,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
        <Label Text="{Binding city_name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**I am using VisualStudio Community Version 2015, In this, How I can get XAML Previewer(Design Previewer), If anyone knows how to get that previwer in VS, please let me know.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the right version of Xamarin, you should be able to get the previewer by going through these menus: **View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer**.

The functionality is in preview right now, according to the [documentation page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/). So you may encounter some unexpected behaviour, and you probably need to be in the Xamarin preview versions update ring.

[image: XAML preview in Visual Studio]